React: Horizontal overflow-x-scroll not working for flex container in Tailwind CSS
The Width of the h1s is too much for mobile devices so i Want to add a scrollable property but the overflow-x-scroll isn't working
      <div>
  
      <div className="mt-16">
        <div className="flex ">
          <div className="hidden md:block font-semibold ">
  
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className=" px-4  ">
              <img src="images/Dashboard.jpg" className="rounded-xl w-full " />
              <div className=" flex justify-center">
                <img
                  src="images/UserDashboard.jpg"
                  className="rounded-full w-28 -mt-16 border-[0.3rem] border-white"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="flex justify-center items-center gap-1">
                <h1 className="text-center text-2xl font-semibold">
                  Ella Solis
                </h1>
                <MdVerified className=" text-blue-500 text-2xl" />
              </div>
              <div className="flex mt-3 items-center gap-2   text-gray-700 justify-center">
                <span className="">0 WishList</span>
                <FaDiamond className="items-center text-[0.5rem] text-gray-500" />

                <span className="">0 Voucher</span>
              </div>

     <div className="mt-8 w-full">
  <div className="overflow-x-auto">
    <div className="flex gap-16 text-xs overflow-x-scroll whitespace-nowrap md:gap-12 md:text-lg">
      <h1
        className={`${showForm === "dashboard" ? "border-b-2 border-[#0D4C90]" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => handleButtonClick("dashboard")}
      >
        Dashboard
      </h1>
      <h1
        className={`${showForm === "userSettings" ? "border-b-2 border-[#0D4C90]" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => handleButtonClick("userSettings")}
      >
        Profile
      </h1>
      <button
        className={`${showForm === "shippingInformation" ? "border-b-2 border-[#0D4C90]" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => handleButtonClick("shippingInformation")}
      >
        Shipping Information
      </button>
      <button
        className={`${showForm === "orderHistory" ? "border-b-2 border-[#0D4C90]" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => handleButtonClick("orderHistory")}
      >
        Order History
      </button>
      <button
        className={`${showForm === "wishlist" ? "border-b-2 border-[#0D4C90]" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => handleButtonClick("wishlist")}
      >
        Wishlist
      </button>
      <button
        className={`${showForm === "review" ? "border-b-2 border-[#0D4C90]" : ""}`}
        onClick={() => handleButtonClick("review")}
      >
        Review
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


              {showForm === "dashboard" && (
                <div>
                  <Dashboard />
                </div>
              )}
              {showForm === "userSettings" && (
                <div>
                  <UserSettings />
                </div>
              )}
              {showForm === "shippingInformation" && (

               <ShippingInformation/>
              )}
              {showForm === "orderHistory" && (
                <div>
                  <OrderHistory />
                </div>
              )}
              {showForm === "wishlist" && (
                <div className="">
                  <Wishlist />
                </div>
              )}
              {showForm === "review" && (
                <div className="">
                  <Review />
                </div>
              )}

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

So I tried to use the Overflow-x-scroll property but it didn't work i even used the overflow hidden to check but it isn't working , i tried removing the container as i thought it may have caused an error but even that doesn't seem to make any change

The high-level display: flex applied style via the flex class implicitly applies min-width: min-content to its children. This means that the children would not shrink in width below their min-content width. Thus, the overflow-x-scroll can never get smaller than its content.
To fix this, consider overwriting the min-width value with something smaller, like 0 via the min-w-0 class:


const { useState } = React;

const MdVerified = ({ ...props }) => <div {...props}>MdVerified</div>
const FaDiamond = ({ ...props }) => <div {...props}>FaDiamond</div>
const Dashboard = ({ ...props }) => <div {...props}>Dashboard</div>
const UserSettings = ({ ...props }) => <div {...props}>UserSettings</div>
const ShippingInformation = ({ ...props }) => <div {...props}>ShippingInformation</div>
const OrderHistory = ({ ...props }) => <div {...props}>OrderHistory</div>
const Wishlist = ({ ...props }) => <div {...props}>Wishlist</div>
const Review = ({ ...props }) => <div {...props}>Review</div>

function App() {
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState();
  const handleButtonClick = (id) => {
    setShowForm(id);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="mt-16">
        <div className="flex ">
          <div className="hidden md:block font-semibold "></div>
          <div className="min-w-0">
            <div className=" px-4  ">
              <img src="https://picsum.photos/1024/96" className="rounded-xl w-full " />
              <div className=" flex justify-center">
                <img
                  src="https://picsum.photos/112/112"
                  className="rounded-full w-28 -mt-16 border-[0.3rem] border-white"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="flex justify-center items-center gap-1">
                <h1 className="text-center text-2xl font-semibold">
                  Ella Solis
                </h1>
                <MdVerified className=" text-blue-500 text-2xl" />
              </div>
              <div className="flex mt-3 items-center gap-2   text-gray-700 justify-center">
                <span className="">0 WishList</span>
                <FaDiamond className="items-center text-[0.5rem] text-gray-500" />

                <span className="">0 Voucher</span>
              </div>

              <div className="mt-8 w-full">
                <div className="overflow-x-auto">
                  <div className="flex gap-16 text-xs overflow-x-scroll whitespace-nowrap md:gap-12 md:text-lg">
                    <h1
                      className={`${showForm === 'dashboard' ? 'border-b-2 border-[#0D4C90]' : ''}`}
                      onClick={() => handleButtonClick('dashboard')}
                    >
                      Dashboard
                    </h1>
                    <h1
                      className={`${showForm === 'userSettings' ? 'border-b-2 border-[#0D4C90]' : ''}`}
                      onClick={() => handleButtonClick('userSettings')}
                    >
                      Profile
                    </h1>
                    <button
                      className={`${showForm === 'shippingInformation' ? 'border-b-2 border-[#0D4C90]' : ''}`}
                      onClick={() => handleButtonClick('shippingInformation')}
                    >
                      Shipping Information
                    </button>
                    <button
                      className={`${showForm === 'orderHistory' ? 'border-b-2 border-[#0D4C90]' : ''}`}
                      onClick={() => handleButtonClick('orderHistory')}
                    >
                      Order History
                    </button>
                    <button
                      className={`${showForm === 'wishlist' ? 'border-b-2 border-[#0D4C90]' : ''}`}
                      onClick={() => handleButtonClick('wishlist')}
                    >
                      Wishlist
                    </button>
                    <button
                      className={`${showForm === 'review' ? 'border-b-2 border-[#0D4C90]' : ''}`}
                      onClick={() => handleButtonClick('review')}
                    >
                      Review
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              {showForm === 'dashboard' && (
                <div>
                  <Dashboard />
                </div>
              )}
              {showForm === 'userSettings' && (
                <div>
                  <UserSettings />
                </div>
              )}
              {showForm === 'shippingInformation' && <ShippingInformation />}
              {showForm === 'orderHistory' && (
                <div>
                  <OrderHistory />
                </div>
              )}
              {showForm === 'wishlist' && (
                <div className="">
                  <Wishlist />
                </div>
              )}
              {showForm === 'review' && (
                <div className="">
                  <Review />
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div id="app"></div>



